# How to set Redis Http Session Timout to Unlimited in Spring

Tags: java, spring, redis

I'd like to make the redis session timeout unlimited in spring.
**@EnableRedisHttpSession** **maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds** is 1800seconds default and I see in the documentation
`[The session timeout in seconds. By default, it is set to 1800 seconds (30 minutes). This should be a non-negative integer.][1]`

So setting it to -1 (unlimited) seems not possible.
FYI : it's already set in tomcat as -1 in web.xml and was working fine until session changed to Redis Http Session management.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the -1 as maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds and it worked well.
Session was unlimited.
However if ever someone thinks about using it, it can cause a memory leak in redis as sessions will never expire (especially for anonymous sessions).