# How to make the user sessions not expire in Redis in Spring Boot applicaion

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-session

I am new to spring-data-redis. I have integrated it with a spring-boot application. As part of this, I have added a few configs as follows:

```
spring.session.store-type=redis
spring.session.redis.namespace=tc
server.servlet.session.timeout=-1
server.servlet.session.cookie.name=UISESSION
server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only=true
```

I don't want the user sessions to persist forever in REDIS. As per [How to set Redis Http Session Timout to Unlimited in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62922386/how-to-set-redis-http-session-timout-to-unlimited-in-spring), even after having the expiry timeout -1, I see all records are getting expired.

That's why I see different `UISESSION` cookie values in request headers every day. I want a permanent value of `UISESSION` for my Spring boot application for a given end user.

I am not getting any idea regarding how to achieve this. Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With spring boot 3, property name is "spring.cache.redis.time-to-live", please cross check your property name set.

Comment: I only want the user sessions stored in REDIS, to not expire. All rest of the keys stored in REDIS should behave as it is. With the property you mentioned in the answer, it will not expire any of the keys in REDIS, will result in leakage. I don't want that.

Comment: You dont want to expire all keys, so, can you please refer https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-ttl.....In my opinion, you need custom solution, while saving keys in redis.

Answer (score -1):

You can adjust the Redis session configuration to set a longer TTL (Time-To-Live) for session keys. This ensures that user sessions remain active for a longer duration without expiring. Here's how you can achieve this:

**Configure Redis Session TTL:**
In your Spring Boot application, you need to configure the Redis session properties to set a longer TTL for session keys. You can do this in your application.properties or application.yml file.
For example, to set the session timeout to 1 hour (3600 seconds), you can add the following

```
spring:
  session:
    store-type: redis
    redis:
      namespace: your-application-name
      flush-mode: on-save
      ttl: 3600 # TTL in seconds (1 hour)
```

**Disable Session Expiration:**

If you want to completely disable session expiration, you can set the TTL to a very large value or to -1 to indicate that sessions should never expire. However, be cautious with this approach, as it can lead to memory consumption issues if sessions are never cleaned up.

```
spring:
  session:
    store-type: redis
    redis:
      namespace: your-application-name
      flush-mode: on-save
      ttl: -1 # Disable session expiration
```